# localStorage add to the next key number

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm receiving messages on Android and I need to store them...

So I need  to do a loop to check if key exists on the device and add if it does add a suffix to it and save it on a new key like `alerta1, alerta2, alerta3`. I think I need to do a `for` loop or something but need some help...

Something like this?:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("alerta" + counter) === null) {    
   localStorage.setItem('alerta1' + counter, message);    
}
```

but first i need to check if it exists...this is all javascript...

Comment: Are you asking how to use a [`for` loop?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: i think so ! i need to to add this value to localstorage

Comment: Then go to the link I provided. `for` loops are very, very elementary and there's examples of how to use them on that site.

Comment: ok ill try again tks

Comment: i tried this but didnt work:for (var i = contador.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("alerta")+contador[i] === null) {localStorage.setItem('alerta'+contador[i], data.message);}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this...

Outputs new keys if they match the current keys.

Essentially duplicating keys with a new suffixed name.

```
function outputKeys(){

    var counter = 0;

    for (var i = keyArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(keyArray[i]) !== null) { 
            counter++;
            localStorage.setItem('alerta' + counter, message);    
        }
    }

}
```